# Ext.MessageBox title with font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I was trying to set a fontawesome icon inside an `Ext.MessageBox` title and i managed to accomplish it using the code below:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
        //iconCls: 'x-fa fa-times-circle',
        title: '<span class="x-fa fa-exclamation"> Error Title</span>',
        message: 'An error occured!!!!!',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
        width: 400
    });
```

Reading the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.Msg.html#cfg-title) i found out that i could set the title using a config object for the [Ext.panel.Title](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.panel.Title.html) component.

But setting the config object like the example below was making the title invisible.

```
title: {
    text: 'Error Title',
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-exclamation'
}
```

Also inspecting the view from the Elements tab of Chrome's Developer tools i saw that there is a div element for icons inside the `x-paneltitle` class.

```
<div class="x-icon-el x-font-icon" id="ext-element-15"></div>
```

How can i set the `MessageBox` title using the `Ext.panel.Title` config?

Comment: Whats wrong with your initial solution?

Comment: It works. I just would like to know how i could do it using the Ext.panel.Title config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fallen into a documentation trap there.

The title config is available on the `Ext.Panel` class instantiation and therefore, technically, also on the `Ext.MessageBox` instantiation, but not on its `show` method, which you call on a singleton that has been pre-instantiated for you by Sencha.

The following would **technically** instantiate a Message Box with a custom title config:

```
Ext.create('Ext.MessageBox',{
    title: {
        text: 'Error Title',
        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-exclamation'    
    }
});
```

**However**, to show the `Ext.MessageBox`, you have to call the `show` method, which has been overridden so as to **overwrite every custom setting you add to the title config**.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
  title: {
    text: 'Error Title',
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-exclamation'
  },
  message: 'You are closing a tab that has unsaved changes. Would you 
  like to save your changes?',
  buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
  icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
  fn: function(btn) {
    if (btn === 'yes') {
        console.log('Yes pressed');
    } else if (btn === 'no') {
        console.log('No pressed');
    } else {
        console.log('Cancel pressed');
    }
  }
});
```

Used it here:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.window.MessageBox.html

It is Classic 6.0.2 but it should still work.

Comment: We are talking `modern`, not `classic`, unfortunately. It won't work with modern because `Ext.Msg` configs are just different enough not to be compatible at all.

Comment: @Alexander Ah i see now. Not available in Modern. I have also fallen for Sencha's Doc's trap :)

Comment: If you run it in modern (inside a sencha fiddle) you will see that there is no title. (you need to change the buttons too buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK)